# Why do I get referenced entities added to context instead of attached, unchanged?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, objectstatemanager

I have attached entities to a context with `EntityState.Unchanged` which will be referenced by a new entity I add later via `DbContext<T>.Add()`. The `Add()` adds the entity, but it also adds the other entities it references to the *added* collection in `ObjectStateManager`, despite the referenced ones being in the *unchanged* collection previously. Under the debugger I see the referenced entities in both collections. So, I end up with inserts occurring on the referenced children entities when I don't want them to.

Comment: Please show the code used for attaching and adding entities.

Comment: It's too complex at the moment. It's in a generic repository implementation. I'll try to scale it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previously attached entities were identical structurally, but they were different references. EF seems to use `ReferenceEquals` under the covers.